# Filter a multi-index dataset (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, filter

I build a pivot-table from a dataset.
Now i want to filter the dataset.
I only want to keep the rows where the setvalue in column 21 is different from the setvalue in 22. How do you do that with multiple indexing ?

```
resultaat.columns
```

results in :

```
MultiIndex([(  'SetValue', 21),
        (  'SetValue', 22)],
       names=[None, 'EquipmentID'])
```

Comment: A sample DataFrame with expected sample output would be more helpful than just the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tuples for select values in `MultiIndex`, cpmpare for not equal and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df[('SetValue', 21)].ne(df[('SetValue', 22)])]
```

If add `values` parameter to `pivot`:

```
df = df.pivot(index=..., columns=..., values='SetValue')

df1 = df[df[21].ne(df[22])]
```